# Cannot create table with underscore in table name MySQL v5.5.14

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1005

I'm using Mysql v5.5.14 and when I try to execute:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LONGBOW_products.universal_partname (
    ->    part_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ->    PRIMARY KEY (part_id)
    -> );
```

It is returning me an error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'LONGBOW_products.universal_partname' (errno: -1)
```

However, when I tried removing the underscore from the table name, it returns true:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LONGBOW_products.universal (
    ->    part_id SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    ->    PRIMARY KEY (`part_id`)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I wonder if you cannot use underscores anymore in table name on newer versions of Mysql?

Comment: Do other tables refer to this table via foreign key if it was previously dropped and recreated? That is a cause of err 1005.  The underscores are fine...

Comment: Don't know a whole lot  of MySQL but found this by googling. See if the solutions suggested in this link help you identify the exact cause. http://verysimple.com/2006/10/22/mysql-error-number-1005-cant-create-table-mydbsql-328_45frm-errno-150/

Comment: Hi @Michael, is there an easy way to know if there are other tables referring to this?

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but `SELECT TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME='universal_partname';`

Comment: Have you tried creating other tables with underscroes in the names? This shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMior, I tried to add one table that has underscore in its name and it is successfully created. Now I confused what could be the problem with universal_partname table.

Comment: Did you try @Sonu's suggestion?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you solved this issue. I got similar issue with a very simple CREATE statement : Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'UCQ.country' (errno: -1).

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-error-codes.html "If the error message refers to error –1, table creation probably failed because the table includes a column name that matched the name of an internal InnoDB table."

However I solved my issue when I looked at mysql_error_log.err:
21107 18:23:19  InnoDB: Error creating file './ucq/country.ibd'.
121107 18:23:19  InnoDB: Operating system error number 17 in a file operation.
InnoDB: Error number 17 means 'File exists'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
InnoDB: The file already exists though the corresponding table did not
InnoDB: exist in the InnoDB data dictionary. Have you moved InnoDB
InnoDB: .ibd files around without using the SQL commands
InnoDB: DISCARD TABLESPACE and IMPORT TABLESPACE, or did
InnoDB: mysqld crash in the middle of CREATE TABLE? You can
InnoDB: resolve the problem by removing the file './ucq/country.ibd'
InnoDB: under the 'datadir' of MySQL.

So I just deleted country.ibd and my CREATE statement ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Database and table names cannot contain `“/”, “\”, “.”,` or characters that are not permitted in file names.

Refer : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Remove "." from table name

Comment: I think the `LONGBOW_products` section is the database name.

Comment: why not try with underscore ""_" ? LONGBOW_products_universal_partname

Comment: Hi @KingFisher, can't be. LONGBOW_products is the database name, not part of the table name.

Comment: He inserted it into databaseName.tableName. For some reason the database name is allowing an underscore in it yet the table name is not.